# Modern treatment of statistical manifolds.

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry

Could someone provide references for a modern treatment of statistical manifolds? I have so far only found treatments that seem quite old, where the notation is somewhat dense to follow, to some extent probably because the font seem adapted to "old-school" typewriters.

Comment: I don't know a comprehensive source, but only a few papers here and there. For example [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81988665.pdf) and [here](https://projecteuclid.org/Proceedings/advanced-studies-in-pure-mathematics/Probabilistic-Approach-to-Geometry/Chapter/Statistical-manifolds-and-affine-differential-geometry/10.2969/aspm/05710303).

Comment: Commenting to mention the 2017 book by Ay, Jost, Vân Lê, and Schwachhöfer ("Information Geometry") which has some basic definitions and so forth in its Chapter 4. (NB: I am just a math tourist in this field, so can't evaluate the book other than "I read some and it was fine".)